# Replace occurrences globally one by one in SublimeText3

Tags: sublimetext3

Let's say we want to replace "apple" to "banana" in every file in the current project. We can do this with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find in Files...) and "Replace" button. But this button replaces all simultaneously. What I want to do is replacing one by one. I know this can be done in a single file with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and "Replace" button.

Is there any ways to do in SublimeText3?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace across multiple files in the same way as you can replace in a single file.

The closest you can get is to use `Find in Files`, make sure `Use Buffer` is toggled on, and then use `Find` to perform the search, a `Find Results` buffer will open. Now you can use `F4` to jump straight to the next results line (`Shift+F4` to the previous), but you need to manually move the cursor to the relevant section(s) of the line and make the alterations manually.

When performing replacements across files, if it's not a simple case of replacing all of some text with some other text, I have found it best to use a regex to make sure that only the matches I want changed will get changed. Occasionally, if creating a complex regex, I will end up testing the regex using `Find` to be certain of what it matches, before then running the same regex with replace.